# Group a list of tuples by their 1st element

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, grouping

Say I have a tuple list that consists of `[("ab", 1), ("ab", 2), ("ac", 3)]`

Using the `group` function would split this list into a list of lists of tuples like so:

```
[
  [("ab", 1)],
  [("ab", 2)],
  [("ac", 3)]
]
```

How would you group the tuple ignoring one of the indices so that they'd be grouped based on one of the elements:

```
[
  [("ab", 1), ("ab", 2)],
  [("ac", 3]
]
```

Would the `groupBy` function be needed in this case?

Comment: Have you tried using `groupBy`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Data.List` `groupBy` function ([docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html)):

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let xs = [("ab", 1), ("ab", 2), ("ac", 3)]
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (\a b -> fst a == fst b) xs
[[("ab",1),("ab",2)],[("ac",3)]]
```

or as suggested by @dfeuer:

```
...
import Data.Function
groupBy ((==) `on` fst) xs
```

Comment: ``groupBy ((==) `on` fst)``

Comment: Nice simplification @dfeuer. Updated my answer